# Bluetooth Bluez: Unable to create crypto contex

Tags: android, linux, bluetooth, bluez

I am using android with Bluez stack, Linux Kernel 3.14 with backports from Linux Kernel 3.19 I am getting the following error message:

```
Bluetooth: hci0 command 0x0c01 tx timeout
Bluetooth: unknown link type 192
Bluetooth: Unable to create crypto context.
```

Any idea of what this error can be comming from? Or any configuration settings I need to put into the linux kernel.

Comment: What code is returning this error? What is the desired output?

Comment: Well my normal bluetooth scanning works but I am trying to get BLE functioning so I am not sure if this error is causing BLE to not work.  And this is coming from dmesg from the init.rc script for bluetooth.

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out, in the kernel config I needed to put CRYPTO_ECB as enabled.